# Übersetzung von "paper accepted for publication in journal"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> His paper was recently accepted for publication in the journal *Science*.

Wie kann man diesen Satz ins Deutsche übersetzen? Mein Versuch:

> Sein Paper wurde kürzlich zur Veröffentlichung im Journal *Science* angenommen.

Ist **Paper** das richtige Wort für so etwas? Und ist **zu** die richtige Präposition in **zur Veröffentlichung** (statt zum Beispiel **fürs Veröffentlichen**).

Comment: Sehr gute Frage. Ich bin vor allem in Bezug auf das Wort "Paper" gespannt, da ich da regelmässig nicht weiß, was ich sagen soll. Nix passt so richtig.

Comment: Paper: Artikel oder Aufsatz.

Comment: Oder "Beitrag".

Comment: @Robert... ja, aber ein Beitrag ist es erst, wenn es genommen wird oder zumindest in der Auswahl eine Zeitschrift war. Wenn's vom Schreibtisch kommt ist es ein Beitrag zur Forschung aber man würde nicht sagen "Der Prof schreibt 4 Beiträge im Jahr"... da wäre sofort die Frage "Beiträge für was".

Comment: @Stephie... würdest du sagen "Während des Doktorats muss man mindestens drei Aufsätze schreiben und veröffentlichen"?

Comment: @Emanuel: Kann man so formulieren. Wahrscheinlich tun sich Geisteswissenschaftler leichter mit dem Begriff als Ingenieure (*wegduck'*), die "denglischen" gerne mit "Papers" rum. (Kein Bashing, ich gehöre als Informatikerin selbst eher zur letzteren Gruppe...)

Comment: Ich kenne auch noch den Begriff **Arbeit** (für paper), die *zur Veröffentlichung eingreicht* oder *angenommen* ist.

Comment: Der Begriff "Veröffentlichung" scheint mir am klarsten zu sein (und ist in den Naturwissenschaften weit verbreitet). Alternativ sind auch Paper, Papier, Arbeit, Beitrag und Artikel geläufig, obwohl ich die ersten beiden z.B. nicht in einer schriftlichen Bewerbung verwenden würde.

Comment: Die Begriffe *Beitrag* und *Arbeit*, wie von @Robert und Takkat vorgeschlagen, haben vor allem das Problem, dass sie zumindest in manchen Fachgebieten weniger spezifisch als *Paper* sind. Speziell im Hinblick auf Journals mag dies nicht so sehr ins Gewicht fallen, aber zumindest auf wissenschaftlichen Konferenzen gibt es eben unterschiedliche Arten von *Beiträgen*, und zwar neben Papers auch Poster, Demos und Workshop-Papers (die in manchen Feldern alle nicht als richtige "Papers" gelten).

Comment: @painfulenglish: "Die Veröffentlichung wurde zur Veröffentlichung angenommen" kann man aber wirklich nicht schreiben. Vielleicht "Die Veröffentlichung wurde zum papering angenommen"?

Comment: @userunknown Klar, das war nur eine Möglichkeit "Paper" zu übersetzen, unabhängig von dem konkreten Beispiel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Paper" ist auf jeden Fall üblich, darüber, ob es Umgangssprache ist, kann man streiten. Wenn ich das Wort vermeiden möchte, benutze ich gerne "Aufsatz". Natürlich geht auch "Artikel", aber wie auch Emanuel betont mir das manchmal zu sehr die Publikationsabsicht. Ich sollte warnen, dass die Benutzung des Wortes "Aufsatz" einigen Jüngeren altmodisch erscheinen kann, ich gebe hier vor allem meinen eigenen Gebrauch wieder.

"Zu" ist richtig, der Rest auch, nur dass ein "Journal" eigentlich eine "Zeitschrift" heißt. "Journal" (mit englischer Aussprache) kommt aber in der wissenschaftlichen Umgangssprache auch vor. Im Deutschen gibt es auch das aus dem Französischen entlehnte Wort "Journal", aber es wird heutzutage eher nicht für wissenschaftliche Zeitschriften benutzt, auch wenn es im Titel von Crelles Journal für die reine und angewandte Mathematik vorkommt.

Comment: Zumindest im naturwissenschaftlichen Gebiet ist es nie ein "Aufsatz".

Comment: Das mag ich als Mathematiker nur bedingt beurteilen können, aber: https://www.google.de/search?q=aufsatz+einstein

Comment: Ich denke, *Aufsatz* wird weniger als *altmodisch* verstanden; es hat einfach eine andere Konnotation. Zumindest als Informatiker stelle ich mir unter einem "Aufsatz" eine Art textbasierte Hausarbeit, wie man sie aus der Schule kennt, vor. *Aufsatz* und *Artikel* / *Paper* /... erscheint mir zunächst einmal wie ein ähnlicher Gegensatz wie *Klassenarbeit* gegenüber *Prüfung* oder *Hausaufgabe* gegenüber *Übung*.

Comment: +1 für den Hinweis auf die Verwendung von "Journal" und "Zeitschrift", wobei mir persönlich neben dem englisch ausgesprochenen "Journal" eher der Begriff "Fachzeitschrift" geläufig ist. *Science* ist eine Fachzeitschrift/ein Journal, während eine "Zeitschrift" eher so was wie die C'T ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper richtig, ich hätte noch darauf hinweisen können, dass "Zeitschrift" nur funktioniert, wenn aus dem Zusammenhang klar ist, dass man eine Fachzeitschrift meint. Wenn man erklären muss, dass Science eine Zeitschrift ist, sollte man wohl besser "Fachzeitschrift" schreiben ;)

Comment: Das Crelle Journal wurde im 19. Jahrhundert gegründet.

Comment: Richtig, eigentlich wollte ich Au h einen Wikipedia-Link setzen, muss ich wohl vergessen haben. Ohne dieses Wissen ist mein auch nicht gut formuliertes Ende wahrscheinlich missverständlich.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Einstein hat auch noch Aufsätze geschrieben, aber heute macht man das nicht mehr. Zumindest ich fände eine Biographie, in der ein heutiger Naturwissenschaftler für seine "Aufsätze" gelobt wird, sehr merkwürdig. Vor allem, wenn sie noch nicht mal erschienen sind, sondern nur akzeptiert wurden. Diesen Beigeschmack sollte man doch eher vermeiden. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Der Ausdruck ist "zur Veröffentlichung annehmen". In einem Journal werden üblicherweise Artikel veröffentlichtet (falls es kein Artikel ist, muss man den Kontext anschauen). Der Artikel wird *von* dem Journal angenommen, obwohl der Artikel *in* dem Journal veröffentlicht wird, also:

> Sein Artikel wurde kürzlich von dem Journal *Science* zur Veröffentlichung angenommen.

Comment: Bleibt die Frage, ob es auch ohne die Perspektive einer Veröffentlichung ein Artikel wäre. Mein Sprachgefühl sagt nein, aber ich bin nicht in der Uni-Szene und weiß nicht, was man sagt.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ein (wissenschaftlicher) Artikel ist ein Artikel, egal, ob oder wo er veröffentlicht ist. Er heißt so, weil er eine bestimmte Form hat. Natürlich ist diese Form darauf angelegt, in einer wissenschaftlichen Zeitschrift veröffentlicht zu werden. "Paper" ist allgemeiner, meistens sind aber Artikel gemeint.

Comment: Dein Satz ist an sich richtig, aber keine korrekte Übersetzung des englischen Ausgangssatzes.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Es ist keine wörtliche Übersetzung, aber so, wie ich es (ohne weitere Informationen über den Kontext) auf Deutsch ausdrücken würde. In diesem Sinne würde ich es schon für "korrekt" halten.

Comment: Auch im Englischen sind "has been accepted for publication in Science" und "has been accepted by Science for publication" möglich und verschieden, ich sehe da keinen Unterschied zum Deutschen.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Aber niemand sagt "wurde zur Veröffentlichung in der Zeitschrift 'Science' akzeptiert". Das würde ich für einen Anglizismus halten, wenn ich es irgendwo lesen würde. Deshalb "von". Die Bedeutung ist so gut wie identisch, und es ist natürlich.

Answer (score 0):

Es scheint weit verbreitet zu sein (siehe, z.B., Google), das Wort accepted mit akzeptiert zu übersetzen:

> Sein Paper/Artikel/etc. wurde kürzlich zur Veröffentlichung in der Zeitschrift Science **akzeptiert**.

oder kürzer

> Sein Paper/Artikel/etc. wurde kürzlich zur Veröffentlichung in Science akzeptiert.

"angenommen" ist natürlich ebenfalls in Ordnung.

Wie im Kommentar zur Frage erwähnt, wird "Paper" unter anderem als

> Paper, Papier, Arbeit, Veröffentlichung, Beitrag, Artikel

übersetzt. Davon scheinen mir Paper und Papier nicht für einen formalen Gebrauch geeignet. (Aufsatz ist mir in den Naturwissenschaften sehr selten untergekommen.)

Auf den Umstand das Journal im Deutschen nicht gängig ist (ebenso wie Science im Englischen kein magazine sondern ein journal ist), wurde schon von @Carsten Schulz hingewiesen.